# dataset.batched() throws ValueError: Value tf.Tensor(9, shape=(), dtype=int32) has insufficient rank for batching

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

trying to do this [tutorial](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/tensorflow-dataset-tutorial/) on windows 8.1 throws: ValueError: Value tf.Tensor(9, shape=(), dtype=int32) has insufficient rank for batching. removing the for loop works fine.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
print("tf version:",tf.__version__)
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(0,10)
dx=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
for x in dx:
    pass
dx = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x).batch(3) # this line throws
```

Comment: Do you need the batching? If not, remove `.batch(3)`.

Comment: i am only trying to get the tutorial to work for me.

Comment: duh! - i am using the variable name x for two different things :(

Answer (score 0):

this was a silly mistake. can't seem to delete the question.

i am using the variable name x for two different things, so of course it fails.